# Set AudioTrack priority similar to SoundPool.setPriority

Tags: android, soundpool, audiotrack

I have several `AudioTrack`s. I want to have Android automatically stop some when others start playing. I'm hoping to be able to just set a priority on each track (similar to [SoundPool.setProirity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setPriority(int,%20int)) and just have the OS do the rest.

Is there anyway to do this, or do I manually have to handle this by calling [stop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#stop())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set priority with AudioTrack, so you have to manually call stop, release. Audiotrack is meant to play a single resource only unlike SoundPool, so there is no priority option.